# Google sheet API values batchupdate, limit of number of ranges in body

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate

The documentation here does not say how many ranges in the body can be updated all at once with one call. Has anybody tested limits?

Right now I have code that updates not many cells at once. I'm trying to see if I should change the code to doing all of it at once. But I don't want to spend the time rewriting the code if there is a limit.

Could it handle 1000 different ranges? My ranges are non-continuous between.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About your following question,

> Could it handle 1000 different ranges?

I think that it's yes. As a simple sample script for testing this, I would like to introduce the following Google Apps Script.

#### Sample script:

This is the Google Apps Script. So when you test this, please copy and paste the following script the script editor of Google Apps Script. And before you use this, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  const max = 1000;
  const data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    data.push({range: `Sheet1!A${i + 1}`, values: [[`A${i + 1}`]]});
  }
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({data: data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"}, spreadsheetId);
}
```

- In this script, the value is put to "Sheet1" using the method of "spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate".

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I couldn't directly confirm the maximum length of `data`. But, in my test, I could confirm that when `mas` is `100000`, no error occurs, and the script worked.
- But when you test with `const max = 100000`, when the sheet has no 100,000 rows, an error occurs. At first, please add rows to 100,000 rows. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)